# Select criteria (with all data have this criteria) Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if I edit, I have 4 table with product, product_to category, product_attribute and attribute_description.

Every table have a relationship.

Like this product :

```
apple, category = 193
dell, category = 100
asus, category = 99
```

And for every category have a child like (apple mac all-in-one 100 (product id= ...), mac notebook 200 (product id = ....)

And every child product have some attribute. (apple mac all-in-one 100 (vga,ram,dll)).

Product :

```
Product_id
```

Product_to_category: (Relationship with product)

```
product_id            category_id
```

Product_attribute : (Relationship with product and attribute_description)

```
product_id            attribute_id
```

attribute_description:

```
attribute_id            name(vga,ram,dll)
```

I try to select **all** attribute with case (any product have this attribute).

Example :

product apple-1 have attribute vga, ram, processor, brightness.

product apple-2 have attribute vga, ram , processor.

product apple-3 have attribute memory, os ,processor,ram.

then select all attribute where (any product have this attribute).
and the answer is **ram** and **processor** (coz, apple1-3 have this attribute).

What i know is select all attribute by 1 from category 193(apple) like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ad.name
FROM product_to_category AS ptc
INNER JOIN product AS p ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN product_attribute AS pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id
INNER JOIN attribute_description AS ad ON pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
WHERE ptc.category_id =193
```

But i want select all name attribute from category apple where (condition any product apple have this attribute) it's mean common attribute.

I want know, attibute what is owned by all the apple product.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please add some sample input and expected output.

Comment: That means, you want to get the common attributes of different products. right? If I am not wrong then you just want the intersection of the sets of attributes of different products.

Comment: @1000111 yeach the common attribute,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using `not exists` to select attributes that are associated with all products.

```
select * from attribute_desc ad
where not exists (
    select 1 from product p
    left join product_to_attribute pta on pta.product_id = p.product_id
        and pta.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
    where pta.attribute_id is null
)
```

`not exists` and `left join ... null` form a double negative. In other words attributes that do not have a missing product association are selected.

Another way using a subquery to count the # of distinct products per attribute:

```
select attribute_id
from product_to_attribute
group by attribute_id
having count(distinct product_id) = (select count(*) from product)
```

Comment: that awesome, i try following you answer but it's error like this  `Unknown column 'ad.attribute_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: does your `attribute_desc` table contain a column called `attribute_id`?

Comment: I try change the sql = `SELECT *
FROM attribute_desc
WHERE NOT
EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN product_to_attribute AS pta ON pta.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN attribute_desc AS ad ON pta.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
WHERE pta.attribute_id IS NULL
)`